# Вывод .BMP через BitBlt с использованием MASM32, WinAPI

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, bitmap, masm32, gdi

Не могу вывести картинку bmp в форму. Уже мучаюсь дня 4. Просто не получается и все. Подскажите в чем проблема. Код:
В pic лежит номер ресурса

```
invoke GetDC, hWnd
mov hDC, eax
invoke LoadBitmap, hInstance, pic
invoke Picture_Draw, hDC, eax

Picture_Draw proc hDC:DWORD, hBmp:DWORD
 local hOld: DWORD
 local hmemDC: DWORD
 local btm: DWORD
 invoke CreateCompatibleDC,hDC
 mov hmemDC, eax
 invoke SelectObject,hmemDC,hBmp
 mov hOld, eax
 invoke BitBlt,hDC,0,0,350,255,hmemDC,0,0,SRCPAINT
 invoke SelectObject,hDC,hOld
 invoke DeleteDC,hmemDC
 return 0 ; Макрос
Picture_Draw endp
```

[image: Ресурсы]

Comment: `invoke SelectObject,hDC,hOld` - не очень понятно зачем это. И после вызова `Picture_Draw` делаете `invoke ReleaseDC, hWnd`?

Comment: И еще, в какой момент у вас происходит рисование? В обработчике сообщения `WM_PAINT` или где-то в другом месте?

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел ошибку! Там проблема была в том, что в функцию invoke BitBlt,hDC,0,0,350,255,hmemDC,0,0,SRCPAINT нужно передавать SRCCOPY

Comment: Не за что) Хорошо что нашли. Я думаю, можно добавить ответом

Comment: Лучше добавить ответ. Обычно не принято добавлять "решено" в заголовок вопроса. С точки зрения сайта вопрос все равно останется неотвеченным.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо! Нашел ошибку! Там проблема была в том, что в функцию
`invoke BitBlt,hDC,0,0,350,255,hmemDC,0,0,SRCPAINT` нужно передавать `SRCCOPY`